# xades4j.UnsupportedAlgorithmException: Unsupported transform on XML Signature provider

Tags: java, xades4j, xml-dsig

I'm trying to create a XAdES-BES signature for a given blob. For this signature, I'd need to add two transforms on the content before it is signed: Base64 (http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#base64) & a custom one (called optional-deflate).

The problems lies with that optional transform. I'm trying to figure out how to implement a custom Transform, register it, and finally have Xades4J use it.

So far I figured a lot (thanks Google and a lot of time), so I got roughly to this: I've got a Provider-class that, in the constructor, puts the new TransformService; In my main code I add my Provider to the Security instance; then, I try to add the transform to my actual to-be-signed object.

Unfortunately, I always get the same error:

```
Exception in thread "main" xades4j.UnsupportedAlgorithmException: Unsupported transform on XML Signature provider (urn:xml:sig:transform:optional-deflate)
    at xades4j.production.DataObjectDescsProcessor.processTransforms(DataObjectDescsProcessor.java:194)
    at xades4j.production.DataObjectDescsProcessor.process(DataObjectDescsProcessor.java:87)
    at xades4j.production.SignerBES.sign(SignerBES.java:173)
    at xades4j.production.SignerBES.sign(SignerBES.java:122)
    at com.mycompany.Test.createXades(Test.java:199)
    at com.mycompany.Test.main(Test.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.transforms.TransformationException: Unknown transformation. No handler installed for URI urn:xml:sig:transform:optional-deflate
Original Exception was org.apache.xml.security.transforms.InvalidTransformException: Unknown transformation. No handler installed for URI urn:xml:sig:transform:optional-deflate
    at org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transforms.addTransform(Unknown Source)
    at xades4j.production.DataObjectDescsProcessor.processTransforms(DataObjectDescsProcessor.java:185)
    ... 5 more
```

So, my code looks like this (abbreviated to what I think is necessary here):

`TransformService` class:

```
package com.mycompany.security;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;

import javax.xml.crypto.Data;
import javax.xml.crypto.MarshalException;
import javax.xml.crypto.XMLCryptoContext;
import javax.xml.crypto.XMLStructure;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.TransformService;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.TransformException;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.TransformParameterSpec;

public class OptionalDeflateTransform extends TransformService {
    public AlgorithmParameterSpec getParameterSpec() {
            return null;
    }
    public Data transform(Data data, XMLCryptoContext context) throws TransformException {
            return null;
    }
    public Data transform(Data data, XMLCryptoContext context, OutputStream os) throws TransformException {
            return null;
    }
    public boolean isFeatureSupported(String feature) {
            return false;
    }
    public void init(TransformParameterSpec params) throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {}
    public void marshalParams(XMLStructure parent, XMLCryptoContext context) throws MarshalException {}
    public void init(XMLStructure parent, XMLCryptoContext context) throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {}
}
```

`Provider` subclass:

```
package com.mycompany.security;

import java.security.Provider;

public final class OptionalDeflateProvider extends Provider {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8849833178389029123L;

    public OptionalDeflateProvider() {
            super("OptionalDeflate", 1.0, "OptionalDeflate provider 1.0 implementing the OptionalDeflate transform algorithm.");
            put("TransformService.urn:xml:sig:transform:optional-deflate", "com.mycompany.security.OptionalDeflateTransform");
    }

}
```

And finally, my main `Test` class, which contains the actual signing. Without that transform, it works (but well, doesn't add the transform, which is necessary). So Base64 works.

```
protected static void createXades(String content) throws Exception {
    /*Get certificate & private key*/
    Certificates c = new Certificates(); 
    c.initSession(); //some helper class where I can get my certificate & private key for signing

    /*Create a document*/
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Element objectElement = doc.createElement("object");
    doc.appendChild(objectElement);
    Element requestElement = doc.createElement("request");
    requestElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(content));
    requestElement.setAttribute("ID", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    objectElement.appendChild(requestElement);

    /*Key provider, signing profile & signer itself*/
    KeyingDataProvider kp = new CustomKeyingDataProvider(c.getCertificate(), c.getPrivateKey());
    XadesSigningProfile p = new XadesBesSigningProfile(kp);
    p.withAlgorithmsProviderEx(new ProviderEx());
    XadesSigner signer = p.newSigner();

    /*Add the optional deflate provider*/
    Security.addProvider(new OptionalDeflateProvider());
    System.out.println("--- installed providers ---");
    for (Provider pr : Security.getProviders())
            System.out.println(pr.getName());
    System.out.println("---");

    /*Test if we can get the transformservice-instance*/
    TransformService ts = TransformService.getInstance("urn:xml:sig:transform:optional-deflate", "DOM");
    System.out.println(ts.getAlgorithm());
    System.out.println("---");

    /*Signed data*/
    DataObjectDesc flatFile = new DataObjectReference("#" + requestElement.getAttribute("ID"))
            .withTransform(new GenericAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#base64"))
            .withTransform(new GenericAlgorithm("urn:xml:sig:transform:optional-deflate"));
    SignedDataObjects dataObjs = new SignedDataObjects(flatFile);

    /*Actual signing*/
    signer.sign(dataObjs, objectElement);
    log(objectElement.getLastChild());
}
```

As you can see I print some things out. I for instance logged that the installation works fine and I also logged the installed providers. I get this as output:

```
--- installed providers ---
SUN
SunRsaSign
SunEC
SunJSSE
SunJCE
SunJGSS
SunSASL
XMLDSig
SunPCSC
SunMSCAPI
OptionalDeflate
---
urn:xml:sig:transform:optional-deflate
---
```

So as far as I can see, the provider has succesfully been registered, the transformservice can be loaded without a problem, ... So I don't really see what's going on?

I've checked the source code of Xades4j as well, and what's happening internally on the line `.withTransform(new GenericAlgorithm("urn:xml:sig:transform:optional-deflate"))` is pretty straight forward:

```
import org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transforms;

...

private Transforms processTransforms(DataObjectDesc dataObjDesc, Document document) throws UnsupportedAlgorithmException {
    Collection<Algorithm> dObjTransfs = dataObjDesc.getTransforms();
    if (dObjTransfs.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    Transforms transforms = new Transforms(document);
    for (Algorithm dObjTransf : dObjTransfs) {
        try {
            List<Node> transfParams = this.algorithmsParametersMarshaller.marshalParameters(dObjTransf, document);
            if (null == transfParams) {
                transforms.addTransform(dObjTransf.getUri());
            } else {
                transforms.addTransform(dObjTransf.getUri(), DOMHelper.nodeList(transfParams));
            }
        } catch (TransformationException ex) {
            throw new UnsupportedAlgorithmException("Unsupported transform on XML Signature provider", dObjTransf.getUri(), ex);
        }
    }
    return transforms;
}
```

The exact line throwing up the error is `transforms.addTransform(dObjTransf.getUri())`. This `transforms` object is a 'standard' apache object (`org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transforms` object). So I'd guess it should be able to get the same TransformService as I do in code litteraly two lines up higher? But it isn't?

Anyone that can point me out what I'm missing? I'll be eternally grateful.

Comment: Additional comment: the solution has been given, but the Transform itself (my `OptionalDeflateTransform` class) does not have to extend `TransformService`, but `TransformClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Apache Santuario [loads transforms from a internal map](https://github.com/apache/santuario-java/blob/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/xml/security/transforms/Transform.java). There is a `register`
method that you probably can use to register your custom transform.

Comment: I found it exactly 2 minutes ago! Apparently there is a `Transform.register(URI, implementation-class)` method, indeed. With that in function I don't even need the whole `Provider` & Security registration system. Thanks!